# Stuck ferment - gingerbeer - or just strange yeast?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, ginger-beer, yeast-nutrient

I've just (as in 2 days ago) laid down a gingerbeer (kit build - first time) - est finished ABV should be 4.0%.

Recipe :

- 2 x Brigalow Gingerbeer Packs
- 3 kg Dextrose mono
- 43L Sterile Water
- 2 packets dried yeast (var unknown)
- 2 packets yeast activator

Start temp 25°C
Checked seals, etc

No apparent activity through airlock after 48hrs. Got concerned and drew a bottom sample.

Brew is "spritzy" with plenty of entrained CO2 - no off notes on taste or smell - but no yeast crust on the top of the fermenter.

I'm worried the ferment has stalled - but there seems to be too much gas for that.

Would adding more yeast or some extra yeast activator be worth a shot? Or is it possible that the yeast is more like a wine yeast and just doesn't produce a crust?

Answer (score 4):

If you have "spritz", which is carbon dioxide gas, then you have fermentation.  No need for concern.  Ginger beer often will not have the yeast krausen layer on top, the yeast remains suspended within the beer itself until it is finished and then will settle out.

All you need now is patience.  Just leave it alone.  All is well.

Cheers, good luck, good health.